# iPad launch image problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

My ipad app is working correctly, the only problem is with launch image. i have added two launch images Default-LandscapeLeft.png, Default-LandscapeRight.png.
but it is showing only landscaperight version very time.

Supported interface orientation
1.Landscape(left Home button)
2.Landscape(right Home button)

PLZ help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iPad Launch Image Orientations Filename Dimensions**

**Default-Portrait.png * 768w x 1004h**

**Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png 768w x 1004h**

**Default-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 748h**

**Default-LandscapeLeft.png 1024w x 748h**

**Default-LandscapeRight.png 1024w x 748h**

**Default.png Not recommended**

**just check your images again. remove images from resources and add it again. make sure clean all target remove build folder from your project. and Run it again it will work.**

Comment: my app is supporting two orientations so i have added two images, you can see i have specified same name

Comment: if you remove Default-LandscapeRight.png then what happen?

Comment: ok problem solved. i just reinstalled app and its working properly now. Thnax for the info Mr. Bhatt

Comment: @problemchild let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1118/discussion-between-rakeshbhatt-and-problem-child)