# Default-LandscapeLeft~iPad.png does not show up

Tags: iphone, ipad, landscape, landscape-portrait, splash-screen

I have some sort of problem, when it comes to customizing the iPad-launch-lcreens of a universal app on iOS5.0+. My app does not read the Default-LandscapeLeft~iPad.png and/or Default-LandscapeRight~iPad.png splashes.

The strange thing about this is, that the app only accepts Default-Portrait~iPad.png and Default-Landscape~iPad.png - but does not read the Default-LandscapeLeft~iPad.png and/or Default-LandscapeRight~iPad.png splashes. I tried various things and read all the tutorials on the web related to that topic.

Things I tried for example:

1. Setting Default-Landscape~iPad.png in XCode->Target->Summary->Launch Image (Landscape). Result: It launches always with Default-Landscape~iPad.png - Splash, but ignores Default-LandscapeLeft~iPad.png / Default-LandscapeRight~iPad.png
2. I deleted XCode->Target->Summary->Launch Image (Landscape). Result: When device in Landscape, it launches with black image. It ignores all Default-Landscape* splashes that are in directory and project bundle.

Has anyone ran into the same problem? I use Xcode 4.3.1 with iOS 5.0 and 5.1. What I am maybe looking for, it a drag and drop interface for landscapeLeft and landscapeRight in Xcode -> Target -> Summary properties (where you set the launch images).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from apple documentation the names should be

- Default-LandscapeLeft.png - left-oriented landscape version.
- Default-LandscapeRight.png - right-oriented landscape version.

Without the ~iPad, since these images are only supported for the ipad.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot. I did confuse it with the ~iPhone / ~iPad modifier for Default.png. It does work now!

Comment: Oh, and then on another target it stopped working. Since I figured out, that I forgot to add the Default-LandscapeLeft.png and Default-LandscapeRight.png to the target. So, do not forget to add the files to your target in the build phases tab!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567971/ipad-launch-image-problem) will help you (about the same question)

> iPad Launch Image Orientations Filename Dimensions
>
> Default-Portrait.png * 768w x 1004h
>
> Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png 768w x 1004h
>
> Default-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 748h
>
> Default-LandscapeLeft.png 1024w x 748h
>
> Default-LandscapeRight.png 1024w x 748h
>
> Default.png Not recommended
>
> just check your images again. remove images from resources and add it
> again. make sure clean all target remove build folder from your
> project. and Run it again it will work.

If it is not working instantly. Try reinstalling your app on the device/simulator.

Hope this helps!